# Using standard FSC Insurance Policy lookup on Account Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, account, related-list, lookup-field, financial-services-cloud

As part of Financial Service Cloud for Insurance, an Insurance Policy object is available with at least 2 lookup relationships to Account i.e `BillingCarrierAccountId` & `WritingCarrierAccountId`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/sforce_api_objects_insurancepolicy.htm

Assuming standard platform functionality is the same for FSC objects, I expected to see available RelatedLists on the Account object for me to display the related Insurance Policies for specific existing Account Page Layouts.

Anybody know why this would be the case for a standard lookup field and if it is FSC specific?